# Is there no possible way to keep the meta data on Preview after we added some text or shape?

Tags: macos, mac, preview

For example, let's say we have an image on the Mac, and we added two text lines to the picture, one with the black or dark blue text as the background, and orange text at the foreground.

Now if we keep the Preview app open, we can arrange the text to different corners of the picture, or resize the text. We can just use "Export" to create the image we want for a few times with different text positions or sizes.

However, once we close the app, we now have the text un-editable (it is burned into the picture). Is there a (secret) way to have the text saved just as if we have the app open, so that the text is editable?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, Preview cannot save to layers, which is what would be needed to do this - that's even if you save to a format that can use layers. jpg, png etc have no layers, tiff can, as can pdf, but you need a more capable app to use them.

Comment: When I need to do things such as you've described, I use _applications_ like [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org) and or [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org), and both are free.